# How to match data frames based on column and impose condition?

Tags: r, dataframe, match, sequence

I have two data frames. Here is an example:

```
x <- rep(c(0,1),3)
y <- c(1999,2000,2001,2002,2001,2002)
z <- data.frame(x,y)
x1 <- rep(0,12)
y1 <- c(1998,1999,1999,2000,1999,2001,1999,2000,2001,2002,2001,2002)
z1 <- data.frame(x1, y1)
```

Basically, newdf is calculated in the way that we pick two rows (row 1 and 2) of z and find match in frame z1 by year.Then we pick up the next two rows (row3 and row 4) of z and again find match in z1 (by year). Function merge will execute all possible combinations of matches however, I would like that each two sequential rows from z did not repeat twice.

```
newdf =(0  1999
        0  2000
        0  2001
        0  2002
        0  2001
        0  2002)
```

Any suggestion would be precious.

Comment: It isn't very obvious how `newdf` is calculated; perhaps you can clarify?  In the meantime, look at the `merge` function.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the explanation there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming what you're trying to do is grab two rows from `z`, match them to `z1` finding the first eligible match for each, and then **remove the already matched rows from both `z` and `z1`**, here is a solution:

```
new.df <- data.frame(x=integer(), y=integer())
while(nrow(z) > 0) {
  match.1 <- match(z$y[1], z1$y1)
  match.2 <- match(z$y[2], z1$y1)
  new.df <- rbind(new.df, z1[match.1, ], z1[match.2, ])
  z <- z[-(1:2), ]
  z1 <- z1[-c(match.1, match.2), ]
}
row.names(new.df) <- NULL
new.df
#    x1   y1
#  1  0 1999
#  2  0 2000
#  3  0 2001
#  4  0 2002
#  5  0 2001
#  6  0 2002
```

This matches your desired output, but your desired output is super ambiguous because all the `x1` values are 0.  It would be a lot easier if your first column in `z1` had more distinguishing values to help infer what you want.

Also, this will break if there are values in `z` that are not in `z1`, or if `z` doesn't have an even number of rows, but I'll leave adding the logic to fix it to you.  Additionally, if you're going to do this for large `z`s you will need to pre-size `new.df` and replace by index instead of `rbind` as I have done here as that gets slow.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works . I have got some help from my friend and we run a loop in a bit different fashion. 

`df<-array(0,nrow (z))
  for (i in seq(1,nrow(z),2))
  {
  for (j in 1:nrow(z1))
   { 
if (z1[j,2]==z[i,2] && z1[j+1,2]== z[i+1,2])
{
if (!j %in% df[1:i-1])
{
df[i]<-j
df[i+1]<-j+1
break
}
}
}
}`

Answer (score 1):

plyr::join might help in this. 
just rename the y & y1 columns in z & z1 by common name lets say as "years" and use

```
abc=plyr::join(z,z1,by="years",match="first",type="left")
```

if you have specific two rows requirement then need to run in loop.